# Spring REST Service converts date-time to number

Tags: java, spring, openapi, openapi-generator

I have build an openapi schema in swagger with an field of type string and format: date-time. In the example window it shows me

> "reportingDateTime": "2022-02-02T10:56:33.310Z"

. But when I call my service it responses

> "reportingDateTime": 1639746778.200000000

I generate the spring api classes with the openapi-generator-maven-plugin version 5.1.0. The resulting response class has this field

> @JsonProperty("reportingDateTime")
> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(iso = org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
> private OffsetDateTime reportingDateTime;

What shall a change to get the correct response type?

Answer (score 0):

Jackson's default settings include formatting dates to timestamps. That's what you're seeing here.

Add the following to your application properties to turn this off:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

Comment: The application.properties would not be used in my context. I add the bean definition to my spring.xml from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46278853/how-to-stop-jackson-from-writing-dates-as-timestamp-in-springmvc. Now I get a big date object and not only the date-time string.

Comment: Are you saying you get an object and not a string? If so, you need to explicitly register the `JavaTimeModule` module in your object mapper.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `DateTimeFormat` for json response may be wrong.

Try to read this article - https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates#java-8