# Prevent spring reactive from returning date as timestamp

Tags: java, spring, date, jackson, spring-webflux

I know that a lot of subject exist about that but i can't find a solution that work for me so i reopened that.

I work on an application powered by Spring Reactive. When i request on an endpoint, the date return as a timestamp. I try a lot of solution to get that Date formatted as 'YYYY-MM-DD  HH:MM:SS' but nothing work.

**Solution i tried :**

- add ***com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda*** to my gradle.build file
- add ***spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false*** to application.properties

But it doesn't work

Use annotation like @JsonFormat("yyyy...") work well but i prefere a global configuration because we're a team working on the project and i want to prevent error from human mistake. Change Date type to LocalDateTime work well too but need a lot of rework on the application and if we can prevent team from that it can be nice.

Someone have an idea on why that global configuration don't work on my app and how to make it work ?

You can find an example of the code just bellow. I remove variable name's for confidentiality reason.
Date is well formatted during code execution, turn into timestamp when parsed to JSON.

**Router**

```
@Override
protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> router() {
    return RouterFunctions.route()
            .path(apiPrefix , builder -> builder
                    .GET(« /list » , myHandler::listSomeObject)
            )
            .build();
}
```

**Handler**

```
@NonNull
public Mono<ServerResponse> listSomeObject(ServerRequest request) {
    return myService.listObject()
            .flatMap(response -> status(HttpStatus.OK).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(response));
}
```

**Service**

```
Mono<List<Object>> listObject();
```

**Object**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Object {

    public final Long id;
    public final Optional<Date> date;
}
```

By the way, in the JacksonAutoConfiguration file i can see this :

```
static {
    Map<Object, Boolean> featureDefaults = new HashMap<>();
    featureDefaults.put(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    featureDefaults.put(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    FEATURE_DEFAULTS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(featureDefaults);
}
```

so maybe the problem is not with Jackson configuration

Thanks a lot for reading

Comment: try to use ObjectMapper class. Once go through this[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46278853/how-to-stop-jackson-from-writing-dates-as-timestamp-in-springmvc)

Comment: You should not use `Optional` for a field. At least I can’t see any advantage over allowing the field to be `null`. `Optional` is for return values from methods. You should not use `Date`. As in not at all. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use some class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: That solution don't work for me because it's using WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and i'm using WebFluxConfigurer so i don't have the method describe in that post and i can't find something like that

I remove Optional. For the date field i'm aware about that but we don't have time now to rework the app.

Comment: I haven't tried but `spring.jackson.date-format` seems promising.

Comment: *but we don't have time now to rework the app.* That’s a situation most of us know. In case you or someone else finds time to rework it at some point in the future, you will be happy that you used a modern type here. Convert to and from  `Date` when interfacing with the legacy code.

Comment: Yeah i prefere java.time lib too don't worry it's on the scope thanks for advice

Comment: The properties you set are for the `java.time` packages and you are using a date embedded in an optional, so it doesn't really apply. Either ditch the `Optional` or write a specialized serializer for it.

Comment: Same result if i delete optional field...

Answer (score 3):

I finally find a way to solve my problem.

I have that class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebFluxConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {...}
```

I figured out removing the @EnableWebFlux annotation fix my problem. Actually, that annotation override default configuration and so, that parameter :

> spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false

was overrided by the default one of WebFluxConfigurer.

Thanks for trying to help guyz and I hope it will be usefull for someone.

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing. It's been my headache. Even in the javadoc of the annotation `EnableWebFlux`, it's telling us to place the annotation on a Configurer bean!